# Adding a views block to a menu? Or adding a menu to a views block?

Tags: 7, routes

I need to create a dropdown menu which consists of the menu items and also a views block of recent nodes. Yes this is technically a megamenu, but how would one build it without a megamenu using only menus and views only?

- How do you make a views show up inside a menu? I'd imagine you would need an extra module for it.
- But if you built a views block and did an entity menu call into the views header, that would work too right?
- Or maybe I'm going about the long way of doing it and should just use a megamenu module, which one would be best?

Of those 3 options which would work best with the least amount of work involved?

Answer (score 2):

To make views show up inside a menu you can use [Menu Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_views). If you only require the functionality your described it's the simplest and easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for menu attach block www.drupal.org/project/menu_attach_block module.

Menu Attach Block allows you to attach blocks to standard core Drupal menu items. This is especially useful for creating complex dropdown menus and mega menus.

Any block can be used, including blocks generated by other modules. Blocks generated by Views are particularly good candidates for embedding.

You can choose to replace menu items with Blocks, or keep the menu items and have the block available by clicking a link which is inserted beside the menu item.